# static constexpr pointer to member function downcasting with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a `Derived` class that inherits from multiple `Base` classes. Each of these base classes has its own `get` function. At runtime I have an index corresponding to the base class whose `get` function I want to call.

I have hundreds of these `Base` classes so I was thinking of storing their `get` functions in a constexpr array of pointer-to-member functions, but I ran into a number of inconsistencies between clang, gcc, and msvc and now I'm not sure what the correct behavior is.
I have a different version of the code that fills this array at runtime and it works perfectly, but it's doing needless work.

I reduced the problem to two base classes instead of hundreds and tried three types of pointer-to-member function calls:

1. runtime downcasting from base to derived
2. compile time downcasting from base to derived (outside of class definition)
3. compile time downcasting from base to derived (inside class definition)

I tried three compilers with C+20 support:

- Clang works for all three
- GCC fails for #3
- MSVC fails for #2 and #3

On GCC and MSVC it doesn't set the `this` pointer to the correct base class. It always uses the address of the first base class, printing `0` instead of `1`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Base0
{
    int value = 0;
    void get() { std::cout << value << std::endl; }
};
struct Base1
{
    int value = 1;
    void get() { std::cout << value << std::endl; }
};

struct Derived : Base0, Base1
{
    #ifdef _MSC_VER // static constexpr downcast pointer-to-member fails in msvc
    static const inline auto Get0 = reinterpret_cast<void(Derived::*)()>(&Base0::get);
    static const inline auto Get1 = reinterpret_cast<void(Derived::*)()>(&Base1::get);
    #else
    static constexpr auto Get0 = static_cast<void(Derived::*)()>(&Base0::get);
    static constexpr auto Get1 = static_cast<void(Derived::*)()>(&Base1::get);
    #endif
};

auto runtimeGet0 = static_cast<void(Derived::*)()>(&Base0::get);
auto runtimeGet1 = static_cast<void(Derived::*)()>(&Base1::get);

constexpr auto constexprGet0 = static_cast<void(Derived::*)()>(&Base0::get);
constexpr auto constexprGet1 = static_cast<void(Derived::*)()>(&Base1::get);

int main()
{
    Derived d;

    // 1
    (d.*runtimeGet0)(); // clang: 0, gcc: 0, msvc: 0
    (d.*runtimeGet1)(); // clang: 1, gcc: 1, msvc: 1

    // 2
    (d.*constexprGet0)(); // clang: 0, gcc: 0, msvc: 0
    (d.*constexprGet1)(); // clang: 1, gcc: 1, msvc: 0

    // 3
    (d.*Derived::Get0)(); // clang: 0, gcc: 0, msvc: 0
    (d.*Derived::Get1)(); // clang: 1, gcc: 0, msvc: 0
}
```

[Try it here](https://godbolt.org/z/TPnMhaf8h)

Questions:

- Which compiler is doing the right thing?
- Why would storing the pointer-to-member function inside the class definition vs outside make a difference?
- Why does MSVC need `reinterpret_cast`? Note that I'm using the `/vmg` and `/vmm` compiler flags. If I comment out the `ifdef` I get the peculiar error:

> error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl
> Outer::Base0::* )(void)' to 'void (__cdecl Outer::Derived::* )(void)'
> note: Cast from base to derived requires dynamic_cast or static_cast

Comment: I'm sure you have a terrible reason for doing this but I'm terrified to ask what it is.

Comment: It's effectively a tuple with runtime element access, where each element has the same API but different sized data members.

Comment: "**[conv.mem]/2** A prvalue of type “pointer to member of `B` of type *cv* `T`”, where `B` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to member of `D` of type *cv* `T`”, where `D` is a **complete** class derived (11.7) from B." Emphasis mine. My guess is that in-class definitions have issues because `Derived` is incomplete at that point. The version with `static_cast` shouldn't compile. The version with `reinterpret_cast` exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Nice find, thanks! so option #3 should be avoided. Could #2 be an MSVC bug? `constexpr auto ptr1 = static_cast<void(Derived::*)()>(&Base1::get); (d.*ptr1)();` also prints `0`. Seems like it doesn't like `constexpr` pointer-to-member function with multiple inheritance. https://godbolt.org/z/3WfxGYqMv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implicit member pointer conversion (`static_cast` is not required) requires that the derived class is complete, which it isn't in your `static` member initializers, which are not a complete-class context, see [[conv.mem]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.mem#2.sentence-1).

The result of using `reinterpret_cast` is unspecified except for the round-trip conversion back to the original type. Using it directly in a member access causes undefined behavior. See [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.reinterpret.cast#10.1).

---

So, MSVC is correct to reject the `static_cast` and Clang and GCC should issue a diagnostic for it as well. Given that this should be ill-formed, there is no sense in asking whether the behavior of the program produced by GCC and Clang for `#3` is wrong except if the developers intended this to be allowed as an extension in which case I wouldn't know where the intended behavior is documented. `constexpr` should not change anything about this.

Because using `reinterpret_cast` like this causes undefined behavior, MSVC is also not wrong in outputting unexpected results for `#3`, again except if MSVC is intending to support this as an extension, in which case I don't know the intended behavior.

For `#2 (d.*constexprGet1)()` MSVC is wrong (according to standard-conformance) to output `0`. It should be `1`. `constexpr` does not affect the value of the member pointer.

Comment: Good explanation for #3, thank you. Still trying to rule out if #2 is a bug in MSVC (constexpr pointer-to-member-function outside class definition). Here's a simplified example: https://godbolt.org/z/b9WPaa51M

Comment: Related: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/invalid-array-initialization-and-ice-with-constexp/714181

Comment: @Petwoip That should produce `1`, not `0`. Seems to be a MSVC bug. (I don't really use MSVC, but if I remember correctly it has a broken pointer-to-member implementation anyway, or at least a non-standard-conform one.)

Comment: yeah I was hoping the conformant `/vmg` flag with `/vmm` would help, but it didn't